# AWS CLI Segmentation Fault

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When I try to run any AWS CLI command in our server- even with just a simple 'aws s3 ls' command - I keep getting 'segmentation fault'.

I know that our server was updated two weeks ago, but last week I was stil able to execute AWS CLI commands with no issue.

Would this be something that the server admin can help resolve?   I reached out to them and I havent heard a peep back.

P.S.  I already checked and confirm that my access keys are still valid.

Comment: Perhaps try reinstalling the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/)?

Comment: Is this happening on every execution or just randomly / occasionally? Are there any other indications of misbehavior?

Comment: @RichardWheeldon yes even with a simple “aws s3 ls” command gives me ”Segmentstion fault” error.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem as well on one of my Raspberry's. Just the message "Segmentation fault" with no further explanation. Python is at 3.9.2 and I even used apt-get to reinstall it. It isn't critical on this particular system but it is odd that it is the only one exhibiting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

"segmentation fault" is a very general error. I assume that you are on a linux instance and can have multiple sources.

You should validate that the python3 installation is working at all, maybe like `python3 --version` .
If this does work, I would try re-installing AWS CLI first and validate that the AWS CLI requirements are fulfilled.